# Button adjustment in scrollView

Tags: java, android

I have created 20 buttons in Linear Layout under ScrollView.But when I change button background all the buttons get mixed with each other. How to separate each button by 4dp.
Plz suggest how to style button here.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by they get mixed with each other? Do they overlap?

Comment: Can you post the layout code and add more description?

Comment: Means button 's boundary line is not viewable because all buttons are same color and their outline is mixed with each other

Comment: Understood. See the answer below

Comment: Yes they are overlapped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `android:layout_margin= 4dp` to separate the buttons.

Comment: thanks kunj ji,it's working but text is not in center now, how to correct it.

Comment: Uss android:gravity=“center” inside the text views

Comment: No sir, it's not working. I'm writing the text inside button, I used  android:padding_centre-verticle="1dp", but it's fetching warning massage that it can be used only above api level 26. Is there other solution

Comment: Use android:layout_centerHorizontal=“true” and android:layout_centerVertical=“true”

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

         <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="BUTTON 1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:textColor="#FFF"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="BUTTON 2"
            android:textColor="#FFF"/>   // to 20 buttons...

            </LinearLayout>
          </ScrollView>
```